# horizontal form css+bootstrap3 (border)

Tags: forms, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

tell me how to do that would border separating INPUT did not reach the edge ?
i used to bootstrap3 Here is a layout:

```
<div class="input-group">
 <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e-mail">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="tel">
</div>
```

or can you tell me another solution ? thank you.

[image]

Comment: don't use bootstrap?

Comment: [Input groups cannot contain multiple `.form-control`s](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E010)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap seems to add padding to the input-group class.

You could possibly override that using:

```
.input-group{
padding:0;
}
```

Or, you could scrap bootstrap (best thing you'll do to learn css), and create your own class:

```css
.group {
  background: blue;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.group:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "@";
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">

  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e-mail">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="tel">
</div>
```